# Swift - 'PFObject is not convertible to NSString'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I've been trying to print the `PFQuery` called in my `viewWillAppear` in the cell but I'm getting the error from this line:

```
cell?.textLabel?.text = message as NSString as String
```

Here's the code for the tableView `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellId: NSString = "cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId as String) as? UITableViewCell
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellId as String)
    }
    let message = myMessagesArray![indexPath.row] as! PFObject
    cell?.textLabel?.text = message as NSString as String
    return cell!
}
```

Here's the `PFQuery`:

```
 var query = PFUser.query()
    query!.orderByAscending("Messages")
    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) messages.")
            self.myMessagesArray = objects
            self.tableView?.reloadData()
        } else {
            println(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, so "Message" is a PFObject. You don't want to assign that object, but one field of it, don't you?

Comment: As debugging you could do `println(message)` if you want to see the contents of message in the console. @freytag is probably pointing you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
let message = myMessagesArray[indexPath!.row] as! PFObject
cell.textLabel?.text = message.objectForKey("Messages") as? String
```